# Set double click to open a file on workspace resource with browser?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I'm writting a plugin in eclipse. I created a new Project in Wizard that when finished, I have structure like this one:

```
My Project
   -> src
     --> index.html
```

I wanna open index.html with internal web browser, and load address `"http://abc:8000"` after I double click it. How can I do that by code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it is related to eclipse plug-in coding.

By default html files will be opened in internal web brower only in eclipse, unless you change the settings in `Windows > Preferences > General > Editors > File Association`.

Edit your index.html like this:

Use **onload attibute and set window location**

`<html>
<header><title>This is title</title></header>
<body onload="window.location='http://google.co.in'">
    Hello world
</body>
</html>`